# Filtering on a Mongo DB capped Collection using Flux

Tags: mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-mongo-java

I have defined my capped collection as below.

```
@Document("#{@environment.getProperty('customProperties.cappedCollection')}")
@Data 
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ActiveRideCapped {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String riderId;
    private GeoJsonPoint location; 
    
}
```

I am re-creating this collection at application startup using below code.

```
@Autowired
MongoOperations mongoOperations;

@PostConstruct
public void createCappedCollection() {
mongoOperations.dropCollection(ActiveRideCapped.class);
mongoOperations.createCollection(ActiveRideCapped.class, CollectionOptions.empty().maxDocuments(20).size(50000).capped());
}
```

The collection in DB looks like below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6037656d2f88af2124ba0d8c"),
    "riderId" : "1",
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            0.1223,
            2.2145
        ]
    },
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603765532f88af2124ba0d8b"),
    "riderId" : "2",
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            0.5468,
            2.7856
        ]
    }   
}
```

I have written a capped repository as below

```
public interface ActiveRideCappedRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<ActiveRideCapped, String> {
 @Tailable
 Flux<ActiveRideCapped> findActiveRideCappedBy();
}
```

and I have written below code to create a stream of filtered records.

```
@Override
public Flux<ActiveRideCapped> getRiderLocationStream(String riderId) {
 return  activeRideCappedRepository.findActiveRideCappedBy().filter(p -> p.getRiderId()!=riderId);
}
```

My requirement is, I should get filtered stream based on the riderId I am passing. So if I pass riderId=1 then I should get flux of all records where riderId!=1. But the filtering isn't working! I am getting all the records present in capped collection.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `p.getId() != riderId` dont you mean `p.getRiderId() != riderId`

Comment: @Toerktumlare : Yes. Made the correction.